# margin-top overlapping element on top

Tags: html, css, margin, styling

Please consider this html snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>no margin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 120px; height: 160px; float:
    left"></div>
    <div style="background-color: blue; width: 160px; height: 120px;
    margin-left: 120px"></div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;
    clear: left; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is the margin of the green div overlapping the red div? I would've expected a visible margin separating the green and the red div. (Tested on Firefox 53.)

Comment: use top:160px; position:absolute; for green div

Comment: That doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `float` property on red element.
and try to positioning other elements Depend on it.

if you want to resolve this, you must to set `float:left` to other box as well.

focus on `float` **meaning**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>no margin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 120px; height: 160px; float:
    left"></div>
    <div style="background-color: blue; width: 160px; height: 120px;
    margin-left: 120px; float:left"></div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;
    clear: left; margin-top: 20px; float:left"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works; but I still don't get, why the margin doesn't have the effect I expected in my snippet.

Comment: try your code with margin 60 in green box.  you will see that the box will move without having float property. because margin Grows up to hit the first element without float property on top. (in this case blue box)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have to float al elments put a div around the top 2 divs as follows:

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>no margin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 120px; height: 160px; float:
    left"></div>
    <div style="background-color: blue; width: 160px; height: 120px; float:left;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;
    clear: left; margin-top: 20px; float: left;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>no margin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 120px; height: 160px; float:
    left"></div>
    <div style="background-color: blue; width: 160px; height: 120px;
    margin-left: 120px"></div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;
    clear: left;top:160px;position:absolute; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin attribute is on the outside of the box model so it is overlapping the red square which is above the green one.

The margin-top  is 20 px  and this is the exact overlapping that we see

as you can see in the example below the margin is outside the box border
[image]

Comment: Yes, but why is the margin ignored in the layout of the green box? My understanding was, that the purpose of margin is to archive exactly the spacing between the red and green box I was expecting. If not, what is the purpose of margin then?